# How do I modify my contourplot to display a region with an huge gradient better?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a contourplot with matplotlib and for my data I have a region where I have a strong gradient - Now I have the problem that matplotlib will display the regions with different colors, according to the selected colormap, and distribute the colors linear over the whole spectrum.

Since 90% of my datapoints are within one end of the spectra, and only this small region acts completely differently, my contourplot looks kind of
monochrome, as you can see in the attached picture[image]

Also, I've added some contours to make the differences in the values more visible. Since we have a huge gradient at a specific spot, there area lot of contours and it is super hard to see the underlying colors or the values.

Is there a good way how to handle such "problematic" regions with matplotlib? Maybe to define another colormap there? I've tried to set some manual levels and to "cut out" the specific region, but it would be nice to find a way to display the value of this region [image: modified scale]

Just to get a feeling: My minimal value to display is around 7, the maximum value is 145 and the average

Here is the important part of my code:

```
z = [] # z is a list of values that i've read in before from a file
X = np.arange(0, 61, 1)
Y = np.arange(0, 151, 1)
z = z.reshape((len(Y), len(X)))
blurred = gaussian_filter(z, sigma=2) # applies a gaussian filter to smooth the plot
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(X, Y) # gets the grid for the plot

procent = np.arange(np.min(z), np.max(z), 5) # levels for the contourlines
newlevels = [5,10,15,20,30,40,50, 80, 100, 120, 140] # sets manual levels for the plot, where I've tried to set a stronger focus on the first part of the spectra
plusmin = plt.contourf(xx,yy,z, origin='lower', extend='both', levels=procent,)
levels = np.arange(np.min(z), np.max(z), 3)

CS = plt.contourf(xx, yy, z, levels=newlevels, extend="both", cmap=cm.viridis)
s = plt.contour(xx, yy, blurred, plusmin.levels, colors='white', linewidths=2)
cbar = plt.colorbar(CS, fraction=0.042, pad=0.04)
ax.clabel(s, fontsize=12, inline=1, colors ='white')
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to scale the colormap so that each colors is equally displayed.

Here is a piece of code I use to handle this kind of problem. There is certainly more proper way to do it with matplotlib, but I do not know it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np
import copy

#-----------------------
def repartition(z):
    """compute the repartition function of an array"""
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(z.flat[:], bins = 1000)
    x = 0.5 * (bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])
    y = np.cumsum(np.array(hist, float))
    y = (y - y[0]) / (y[-1] - y[0])
    return x, y

#-----------------------
def adjustcmap2data(Z, cmap, N = 16384):
    """scale the colormap so that all colors are equally displayed"""
    def cmap2xs(cmap):
        "convert cmap to matrix"
        sd = cmap._segmentdata
        xr = [tup[0] for tup in sd['red']]
        xg = [tup[0] for tup in sd['green']]
        xb = [tup[0] for tup in sd['blue']]
        return tuple([np.array(x) for x in xr, xg, xb])

    def xs2cmap(cmap, xr, xg, xb):
        "convert matrix to cmap"
        sd = cmap._segmentdata
        for k in 'red', 'green', 'blue':
            sd[k] = list(sd[k])
            for i in xrange(len(sd[k])): sd[k][i] = list(sd[k][i])
        for i in xrange(len(sd['red'])):   sd['red'][i]    = (xr[i], sd['red'][i][1], sd['red'][i][2])
        for i in xrange(len(sd['green'])): sd['green'][i]  = (xg[i], sd['green'][i][1], sd['green'][i][2])
        for i in xrange(len(sd['blue'])):  sd['blue'][i]   = (xb[i], sd['blue'][i][1], sd['blue'][i][2])
        for k in 'red', 'green', 'blue':
            sd[k] = tuple(sd[k])
        return colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('mycmap_%010.0f' % (np.random.randn() * 1.e10), sd, N)

    x, y = repartition(Z)
    x = (x - x[0]) / (x[-1] - x[0])
    xr, xg, xb = cmap2xs(cmap)
    xrr = np.interp(xr, xp = y, fp = x)
    xgg = np.interp(xg, xp = y, fp = x)
    xbb = np.interp(xb, xp = y, fp = x)
    for x in xrr, xgg, xbb:
        x[x < 0.] = 0.
        x[x > 1.] = 1.
        x[0], x[-1] = 0.,  1.
        x.sort()
    mycmap = xs2cmap(copy.deepcopy(cmap), xrr, xgg, xbb)
    return mycmap


#---------------------
def fake_data():
    """generate a fake dataset"""
    x = np.linspace(-1., 1., 256)
    y = np.linspace(-1., 1., 256)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = np.zeros_like(X)
    #create background noise
    for _ in xrange(100):
        x0 = np.random.randn() 
        y0 = np.random.randn()
        Z += 0.05 * np.exp(-0.5 * (((X - x0) / 0.1) ** 2. + ((Y - y0) / 0.1) ** 2.))
    #add strong peak
    Z += np.exp(-0.5 * (((X - 0.5) / 0.3) ** 2. + ((Y - 0.5) / 0.02) ** 2.))
    return X, Y, Z

#---------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    X, Y, Z = fake_data()
    plt.figure()
    cmap = plt.cm.spectral
    plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap = cmap)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors = "w")
    plt.gcf().show()

    plt.figure()
    scaledcmap = adjustcmap2data(Z, cmap = cmap)
    plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap = scaledcmap)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.gcf().show()

    raw_input('pause')
```

which should give you the following results
1) linear colorbar
[image]
2)  scaled colorbar
[image]